# Determining which account sent tweet

Tags: objective-c, ios5, twitter

Given the following code:

```
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController class]) 
{
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweeter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [tweeter setInitialText:@""];
    [self presentModalViewController:tweeter animated:YES];
}
```

The user has the ability to select which account to send a tweet from, on devices which have more than one account enabled.

Is there anyway within the delegates, to figure out which account was used to send the tweet when more than one is present? As I wish to log it server side for analytics's.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to determine this